# How can I better structure this code?

Tags: python, code-cleanup

I have an `lxml.objectify` data structure I get from a RESTful web service. I need to change a setting if it exists and create it if it doesn't. Right now I have something along the lines of the following, but I feel like it's ugly. The structure I'm looking in has a list of subelements which all have the same structure, so I can't just look for a specific tag unfortunately.

```
thing_structure = lxml.objectify(get_from_REST_service())
found_thing = False
if thing_structure.find('settings') is not None:
    for i, foo in enumerate(thing_structure.settings):
        if foo.is_what_I_want:
            modify(thing_structure.settings[i])
            found_thing = True
if not found_thing:
    new = lxml.etree.SubElement(thing_structure, 'setting')
    modify(new)

send_to_REST_service(thing_structure)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, the structure isn't too bad (assuming you need to call `modify` on **1+** items in the settings -- if "just one", i.e., if the `is_what_I_want` flag is going to be set for one setting at most, that's of course different, as you could and should use a `break` from the `for` loop -- but that's not the impression of your intentions that I get from your Q, please clarify if I've mistead!).  There's one redundancy:

```
for i, foo in enumerate(thing_structure.settings):
    if foo.is_what_I_want:
        modify(thing_structure.settings[i])
        found_thing = True
```

Having `i` and using it to get again the same `foo` is no use here, so you can simplify to:

```
for foo in thing_structure.settings:
    if foo.is_what_I_want:
        modify(foo)
        found_thing = True
```

You'd only need the index if you were to *rebind* the item, i.e., perform an assignment such as `thing_structure.settings = whatever`.  (BTW, a name other than `foo` wouldn't hurt;-).

Comment: The `foo` name isn't what I use in the actual code, I was just trying to reduce the complexity a bit and not put anything specific to my codebase -- more the general structure. I do in fact rebind the item, which is why I used `i`.

Comment: @Daenyth, the `foo` was pretty obvious (which is why I had a smilie there), but removing the crucially-different operation of item rebinding was an oversimplification -- it does make all the difference whether you're doing such rebinding (thus need `enumerate`) or don't (thus not need it).  With your new info, and always assuming you need to be able to call `modify` one **or more** times (not just once), there's no substantial simplification that I can see (some tricks, yeah, but they might damage clarity rather than enhance it).

Comment: Alex, can you take a look at this when you get a chance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826473/boolean-operations-in-python-ie-the-and-or-operators ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would write this:

```
thing_structure = lxml.objectify(get_from_REST_service())
if thing_structure.find('settings') is not None:
    foos = [foo for foo in thing_structure.settings if foo.is_what_I_want]
        or [lxml.etree.SubElement(thing_structure, 'setting')]
    for foo in foos:
       modify(foo)
send_to_REST_service(thing_structure)
```

I don't care for `is not None` and eliminate it where I can. It it is possible here, I would write:

```
if thing_structure.find('settings'):
```