# can anyone tell me how this syntax is called and what it does?

Tags: javascript

I was reading through Ionic's source and stumbled on this part here.

```
fromTemplateUrl: function(url, options, _) {
  var cb;
  //Deprecated: allow a callback as second parameter. Now we return a promise.
  if (angular.isFunction(options)) {
    cb = options;
    options = _;
  }
  return $ionicTemplateLoader.load(url).then(function(templateString) {
    var modal = createModal(templateString, options || {});
    cb && cb(modal);
    return modal;
  });
}
```

What's the syntax in line 10 ,  **"cb && cb(modal);"** ,  called and what does it do?

The conditional && is confusing me

Comment: [On && and || in Javascript](http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/510)

Comment: It's just a cuter way of writing `if(cb) cb(modal)`.

Comment: that makes sense, is there a name for this kind of shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
undefined && 42 // undefined, the second part wouldn't be evaluated
'defined' && 42 // 42
undefined || 42 // 42
'defined' || 42 // 'defined', the second part wouldn't be evaluated
```

That way this thing is working.

Answer (score 3):

thanks everyone, the answer by jon, a shorter way for

```
if(cb) cb(modal)
```

combined with the explanation at [Assignment with double ampersand "&&"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878612/assignment-with-double-ampersand) answer my question

I'll remember this as "short if exists syntax"