# How should I understand this line? can anybody elaborate on this?

Tags: javascript

```
categoryId = categoryId === '' && location.pathname.match(regExp) ?location.pathname.match(regExp)[1] : categoryId
```

I know this is a ternary operator but what does `categoryId === '' && location.pathname.match(regExp)` do here? particularly no clue on `'' && location.pathname.match(regExp)`
is it a boolean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assignment with double ampersand "&&"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878612/assignment-with-double-ampersand)

Comment: Then you should have a look at the documentation of [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Explicit grouping parentheses and more conventional spacing may help: `categoryId = ((categoryId === '') && (location.pathname.match(regExp))) ? location.pathname.match(regExp)[1] : categoryId`

Answer (score 2):

So I will take you through the piece of code you have provided as detailed as my free time now can permit me and from the top of my head.

`categoryId` is a variable that is accepting the result of what is on the right. thus the `=` sign.

`categoryId === ''` This part here is simply making a comparison between the results in `categoryId` to an empty string `''` which will return a boolean. So its saying "is the result in `categoryId` an empty string? `true` or `false`.

`&&` this is saying that we are going to check under condition so check the above one and another...

`location.pathname.match(regExp)` this is the 2nd check... checking if a url path matches a certain regex definition/condition in `regExp` (you have not provided that so I can't say much there)

Now note that due to the use of `&&`, both conditions must return `true` before the `true` statement is run else it will be `false`.

`?` this is saying; if true, run the next condition/statement

`location.pathname.match(regExp)[1]` this is the condition/statement it will run if result is true.

`:`  this means if it is false, run the next condition/statement

`categoryId` this is the condition to run when the result is false.

This type of conditional statement is called a "Conditional/Ternary Operator" find a bit more details here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

I hope this helps. If its not clear let me know so I clarify. Best way to learn!

Comment: _"So I will take you through the piece of code you have provided as detailed as my free time now can permit me and from the top of my head."_ - How is this relevant for the answer?

Comment: Just to let him know am running through the whole code. If you think it is irrelevant, please feel free to edit. Team work makes the dream work!