# Why I need to access multiple nested properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Please don't close my question. Earlier it was closed with a wrong solution, [Assignment with double ampersand "&&"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878612/assignment-with-double-ampersand).

Please help me understand the Redux code. Why can't I use directly error.response.data.message below? Why I need to iterate through each layer?

```
export const register = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/register",
    async ({ username, email, password }, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const response = await authService.register(username, email, password);
            thunkAPI.dispatch(setMessage(response.data.message));
            //Testing by omiting below
            //return response.data;
        }
        catch (error) {
            //Why not just error.response.data.message?
            const message = (error.response && error.response.data &&
                error.response.data.message) || error.message
            error.toString();
            thunkAPI.dispatch(setMessage(message));
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue();
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: `error.response.data.message` can only work if you're sure that the property path exists. If `.data` didn't exist on `response` it would error when you try and access `message`, same with `.data` is `response` didn't exist. Using optional chaining (`?.`) with the nullish coalescing operator (`??`) is the more modern way of writing this: `const message = error.response?.data?.message ?? error.message` (although they behave slightly differently)

Comment: First off, nothing to do with redux. This is just basic JS error handling when the error object can have different shapes. Some errors, like a basic connection error (wifi down or something) don't have a response associated with them, since a request couldn't be made in the first place. Then you only get `error.message`. This code is trying to handle both cases, error responses from the auth service but also more fundamental errors.