# and-or trick in Python

Tags: python-2.7

What's the purpose of the "and-or" trick?

i.e.

```
>>> a = ""

>>> b = "second"

>>> 1 and a or b

'second'
```

Comment: It’s like an inline `if` that works less reliably.

Comment: To be specific, you’re seeing it work less reliably here, because `a` is falsy. With anything truthy, it would work like `a if 1 else b`.

Comment: Yea, I should check to see if a is never false. I'm more asking why I would use the "and-or" trick instead of an if-statement?

Comment: Also read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826473/boolean-operations-in-python-ie-the-and-or-operators

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was just a way to mimic the conditional operator (aka. "ternary" operator) found in the C family of languages.  In the past, there was no direct equivalent expression.  The following expressions are *somewhat* equivalent:

```
# in python
a and b or c
```

```c
// in C
a ? b : c
```

Don't use it though.  Due to the semantics of Python, if `b` was falsy, the expression will evaluate to `c`.

They have since provided a proper syntax for this construct as of Python 2.5 ([PEP 308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)).

```
b if a else c
```