# Why doesn't "or" return a boolean?

Tags: python

```
num = '5'
result = num or None
print(result)  # 5

num = ''
result = num or None
print(result)  # None
```

I don't understand why this works because I thought "or" will check if one side is True and if so it will return True. But it returns either the value of num or None.

Comment: @coldspeed:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/3826473/1079354

Comment: Because empty strings are False...

Comment: @Makoto Thanks. My priority was closure over dupe accuracy.

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks, the first link answers my questions.